# Как разделить один ассоциативный массив на два массива

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив

```
array (size=7)
'date_of_sale' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2022-07-22' (length=10)
      1 => string '2022-07-22' (length=10)
  'software_name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Pro' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Push' (length=4)
  'customer' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Pro' (length=3)
      1 => string 'Push' (length=4)
  'software_price' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '3443' (length=4)
      1 => string '2090' (length=4)
  'amount' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
  'price' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '3443' (length=4)
      1 => string '2090' (length=4)
```

Как я могу разделить его на два массива и записать в один общий таким образом?

```
array(
  array(
  'date_of_sale' =>  string '2022-07-22' 
  'software_name' => string 'Pro' 
  'customer' => string 'Pro'
  'software_price' => string '3443' 
  'amount' => string '1' 
  'price' => string '3443'), 

  array(
  'date_of_sale' =>  string '2022-07-22' 
  'software_name' => string 'Push' 
  'customer' => string 'Push'
  'software_price' => string '2090' 
  'amount' => string '1' 
  'price' => string '2090'
));
```

Comment: Откуда-то с фронта приходит?

Comment: Да, приходит из инпутов в форме

Comment: Инпуты тогда надо именовать не `price[]`, `customer[]`. A вот так: `items[1][price]`, `items[2][price]`, `items[1][customer]`, `items[2][customer]`. И тогда `$_POST[items]` будет прям как надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Взять значение по ключу `date_of_sale` (положить в переменную `$elemets`)
2. Посчитать сколько элементов в массиве будет встречаться через `count($elem)` и положить в переменную `$elementsCount`;
3. Объявить переменную как массив, куда будет складываться результат (`$result`)
4. Сделать два цикла: внешний через `for` от 0 до `$elementsCount` и внутренний `foreach as $key $value`, который будет проходиться по главному массиву со всеми ключами
5. Во внутреннем цикле формировать ассоциативный массив `$element[$key] = $value`
6. За пределами внутреннего цикла складывать ассоциативный массив в результирующий `$result`

Comment: Огромное спасибо